# Divergence and curl integral surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

Show that if $f=0$ on the unit sphere $r=1$ then
$$f(0,0,0) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{-1}{4\pi}\iiint_{D_\epsilon}\frac{(x,y,z)\cdot\nabla f}{r^3}\,dV,$$
where $D_\epsilon = \{\epsilon \leq r \leq 1\}$.

Please help me and guide me how to solve this problem i totally have no idea how should i solve it.

Comment: Which course/book is this from? Have you seen the divergence theorem?

Comment: Its from stwerts calculus yes there i didn't get the right idea

Comment: $\frac{\vec r }{r^3}\vec \nabla f(r)=\nabla(\frac{\vec r f(r)}{r^3})-(\nabla(\frac{\vec r }{r^3}))f(r)=\nabla(\frac{\vec r f(r)}{r^3})+(\Delta\frac{1}{r})f(r)$. First term is transformed into the flow trough the surface of unit sphere ($=0$); $\Delta\frac{1}{r}=-4\pi\delta(\vec r)$